# Step by step guide for benchmarking PHP project

Tags: php, testing, benchmarking

Can anyone guide me how to load test/benchmark a project written in plain procedural PHP (no framework) and MySQL to identify the bottleneck ?
The project uses SESSION to store some values.

I've the last version of WAMP !

*[On SO i found JMeter to do the job, but there was no step by step guide, neither i found it on the JMeter's site. Looking for help from you.]*

Comment: If you put close or down vote please explain your reason. If i'm missing some info which is required to answer this question state that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to profile your code to find out, which part of it takes all the time, you're looking for a profiler.
With WAMP, I'd recommend [the xdebug profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) with [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) to visualilze the data.

On the other hand, if you want to know, how much your site can take, you should take a look at [Apachebench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), which should come with WAMP.
You didn't specify, how complex your benchmarking needs are, but apachebench should make it possible.

Comment: +1 for Apachebench, i used xdebug, they were not showing any error, but it was just showing time function were taking to run ! How can it help me ? coz in my system if a code takes 10 milisec on the server it can take 20 or 5 milisecond !

Comment: But your system might handle 1000 requests/second whereas your server might only handly 50, 2 or 20000.

Comment: The output from a profiler will show you what part of your code will take the most time, so you can focus on optimising that (of course, results might get skewed if your production environment has different characteristics, e.g. because it has a way larger dataset or a SQL server on a different machine etc.)

Comment: can i run ApacheBench from Win Console ? i viewed the documentation but there was no example :(

Comment: WAMP should include ab.exe, you can start it from the console.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHPUnit for testing:

http://jsdoodnauth.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/installing-wamp-and-phpunit-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Unit Test based development.

This allows you to produce bug free code. It also benchmarks for time.

And PHPUnit definitely is the way to go